# Android Studio Preferences issue with creating settings

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-preferences

I'm currently trying to implement a settings function on android studio using kotlin. I am referencing this [guide](https://tutorials.tinyappco.com/Kotlin/Preferences). I am using a mac and an external android device to run the applications

However, I have run into an issue where my application runs successfully (opens, other aspects of application performs fine), but crashes whenever i try to click on the "settings" option.

Below are functions from my MainActivity class

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.iSettings) {
            val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

Below is the code for my SettingsActivity class

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, MySettingsFragment())
            .commit()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Below is the code for MySettingsFragment class

```
class MySettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

My xml code for the settings/preferences page. Currently filled with code examples from the guide above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="notifications"
        android:title="Enable message notifications"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="feedback"
        android:title="Send feedback"
        android:summary="Report technical issues or suggest new features"/>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Also, my menu xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/iSettings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

[Dropdown menu at top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HNAg.jpg)

[Settings option which crashes the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fLAN.jpg)

Please help!

Comment: May be, inflating fragment first and then calling `super.onCreate()` later causing the crash. Copy the stack trace from your Logcat and add in your question here.

Comment: what's the error? Paste the logcat error so we can check the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your responses. Adding the activity to manifest and changing the `super.onCreate()` fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good, but we need a little bit more context on the problem, like how are your xml set. I'll write some notes so you can determine what's missing on your app.

1. Preferences files should be in `res/xml/preferences.xml`
2. In your SettingsActivity you should have a `FrameLayout` with an id that you could set in your `.replace(android.R.id.content, MySettingsFragment())` and instead of `android.R.id.content` you use yours.
3. `onCreateOptionsMenu` should return a `Boolean` and you are always sending the same return `super(..)` you should change it to :

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when(item.itemId){
        R.id.iSettings -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            true
        }
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

4. Have you declared your Activity in the `manifest.xml`?
5. You should replace the fragment after the `setContentView` in your `SettingsActivity` as :

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.your_id, MySettingsFragment())
                .commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your response. I didn't know there was a need for the manifest. It worked after declaration and also declaring the `super.onCreate()`.